# Multistep command and message collector discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, command

I'm trying to create a multistep command and after the last edit of the embed I want to collect what the user reply. I tried await message , message collector but I did not succeed.

This is the last part of the command. Thanks for your help

```
                    .then(collected => {
                    var date = collected.first().emoji.name
                    switch (date){
                        case '1️⃣':
                            message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Tu as choisis d'ajouter un devoir pour lundi`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
                            var date = 'lundi'
                            break;
                        case '2️⃣':
                            message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Tu as choisis d'ajouter un devoir pour mardi`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
                            var date = 'mardi'
                            break;
                        case '3️⃣':
                            message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Tu as choisis d'ajouter un devoir pour mercredi`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
                            var date = 'mercredi'
                            break;
                        case '4️⃣':
                            message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Tu as choisis d'ajouter un devoir pour jeudi`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
                            var date = 'jeudi'
                            break;
                        case '5️⃣':
                            message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Tu as choisis d'ajouter un devoir pour vendredi`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
                            var date = 'vendredi'
                            break;
                    }setTimeout(() => 5000) 
                     m.reactions.removeAll()
                     const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('RED')
                    .setTitle('Entrer le descriptif du devoir')
                    setTimeout(() => 7000) 
                
                    m.edit(newEmbed)
                    
                    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
                    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter,{time:10000}).then(collected =>{
                        console.log(m)
                    })
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong? Did you get an error?

Comment: That send me this in the console : 
`Message {
  channel: TextChannel {
    type: 'text',
    deleted: false,
    id: '834932687995011112',
    name: 'cmd',
    rawPosition: 2,
    parentID: '777092693264039948',
    permissionOverwrites: Collection [Map] {},
    topic: null,
    lastMessageID: '850440734573199370',
    rateLimitPerUser: 0,`

and other parameters

Comment: That looks like expected behavior to me. What were you expecting?

Comment: If the user reply " Hello 123 " I want to have " Hello 123" in return.

Comment: You did `console.log(m)`, it logged `m`. What's the issue?

Comment: The probleme is I want to have what the user reply. But I dont find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) method returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) (a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)).

Since you want the output to be an array of strings, you can do something like this:

```js
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter,{time:10000}).then(collected =>{
  const list = [];
  collected.forEach((message) => {
    list.push(message.content);
  });
  console.log(list); // ["hello", "world"]
});
```

If you only want a single message, you can use the [`MessageCollectorOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageCollectorOptions)'s `max` property and set it to 1:

```js
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter,{time:10000, max:1}).then(collected =>{
  // in case the user did not answer
  if (typeof collected.first() === "undefined") {
    return;
  }
  const string = collected.first().content;
  console.log(string); // "hello"
});
```